# Post Patterns, Adding Custom Fields to Subject Area

Tags: custom-fields, activities

Post Patterns, I Want To Add Custom Data To The Subject Area.

By info "Custom tokens (based on custom data) can be added for organizations as well. These tokens will not be displayed in the list of available tokens, but can be added manually. The format is {contact.custom_12} – where 12 is the ID of the custom data field. To find the custom data field ID, go Administer > Customize Data & Screens > Custom Fields and click ‘edit’ on the field you want to use. Look at the URL. The last part of the URL will be an equal sign and a number (=12). The number (12 in this example) is the id of that custom field." I reached the ID number 8 with this method and I made experiments by adding many options to this information and adding sub-options to its individual or content. The e-mail sending does not receive the information I added to the activity. Only the code I added appears in the mail. Is this a problem or I just can't.

How I Do It.

"*Administer > Customize Data & Screens > Custom Fields*" I'm logging into the department.

Then I get the code that is in the URL. =8
[image]

Then I log in to the "Cases - Send Copy of an Activity" section, add {contact.custom_8} at the end of the Subject field and save.
[image]

The result is as follows. I dont want this. I want the data I added to the ID to be output.
[image]

Comment: What does custom_8 refers to? contact field?

Comment: Custom Data: Administer > Customize Data & Screens > Custom Fields

Comment: Custom Fields, Here is a field title I created. It has subfields in it. It has ID 40 on it. However, it cannot retrieve data with any of them. I forgot to add $ to the beginning of where I added the code. I added. There is no coda error. BUT still not pulling data.

Comment: and the custom extends to ?

Comment: I do not understand.